# receiving PNG file in django

Tags: python, django, png, wsgi, falconframework

I have a falcon server that I am trying to port to django. One of the falcon endpoints processes a request that contains a PNG file sent with `content_type = 'application/octet-stream'`. It writes the data to a file maintaining the correct PNG structure.

The falcon code does this:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=req.stream, environ=req.env)
```

and then writes the png like this:

```
fd.write(form[key].file.read())
```

I cannot figure out how to do the same thing in django. When my view is called the data in `request.POST[key]` has already been decoded to unicode text and it's no longer valid png data.

How can I do this with django? Should/can I use `cgi.FieldStorage`? The request I get (of type `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest`) does not have a stream method. I'm sure there's some way to do this, but I have not come up with anything googling.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the client to set the file and filename fields each part of the multipart and then I was able it iterate through request.FILES and successfully write the files as PNG.